# couldn't set background image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an element using blogger api and adding a background image in it as shown in below code:

```css
.pimg{height:300px;width:300px}
```

```html
<div id='content'></div>
<script>
function handleResponse(response) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
console.log(response);
  response.items.forEach(item => {
    const html = parser.parseFromString(item.content, 'text/html');
    const img = html.querySelector('img');
    const url = img ? img.src : '';
const images =url;
const content =item.content;
var count = 200;
var result = content.slice(0, count) + (content.length > count ? "..." : "");
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += `<div class="post-outer">
<h2 class="entry-title">
<a href="${item.url}" id="pt">${item.title}</a>
</h2>
<div class="pimg" style="background-image: url("${images}");">
</div>
<div class="post-inner">
${result}
<a href="${item.url}" id="pt">[Continue Reading]</a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>`;
  })
}
</script>
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/6626813856655473541/posts?maxResults=4&callback=handleResponse&nextPageToken&key=AIzaSyD_BnKD6_7Fygmd6PZc5ReEDek842iMOzo"></script>
```

This is line in above code where i'm adding background image:
`<div class="pimg" style="background-image: url("${images}");">`
Original image URL is this:`https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-7vVCeLa3OuM/WzjdK1ovHPI/AAAAAAAABwo/mfeTNYcQ294d5kSAPifOP3VQMyrUmWIBwCLcBGAs/s1600/summar-large-card.png`

But when my content loads background image set as:
`<div class="pimg" style="background-image: url(" https:="" 4.bp.blogspot.com="" -7vvcela3oum="" wzjdk1ovhpi="" aaaaaaaabwo="" mfetnycq294d5ksapifop3vqmyrumwibwclcbgas="" s1600="" summar-large-card.png");"="">
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
"background-image: url('${images}');"
```

Comment: How I do that in this loop

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use CSS instead

```
<style>
.pimg{
background-image: url("paper.gif");
}

</style>

<div class="pimg"></div>
```

Comment: How I do that, This code run a loop which set different image of different divs